# Harvesting repository // "From=>" and "Until=>" with user input variable

Tags: date, perl, user-input, stdin, oai-pmh

I am using „from=>“ and “until=>” while harvesting a repository with OAI-PMH written in Perl. I tried to let the user type in start- and end-date with `<STDIN>` in format yyyy-mm-dd. But instead of giving me back the records/results the compiler seems to ignore my query / request, at least it does not give me any results. I have enclosed the relevant parts of the code below. Thanks for your help!

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Net::OAI::Harvester;
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $harvester = Net::OAI::Harvester->new( 
    baseURL => 'https://opus4.XXX/oai'
);

my $weekAgo = localtime() - ONE_WEEK;
$weekAgo = $weekAgo->ymd;

my $monthAgo = localtime() - ONE_MONTH;
$monthAgo = $monthAgo->ymd;

print "Please enter a number \n
        1 for last weeks records \n
        2 for last months records \n
        3 for records from ... until ...\n";
my $input = <STDIN>;

[...]
elsif( $input == 3 ) {
        print "enter start date (yyyy-mm-dd): ";
        my $from = <STDIN>;
        print "Enter final date (yyyy-mm-dd): ";
        my $until = <STDIN>;

        my $list = $harvester->listRecords(
            metadataPrefix  => 'oai_dc',
            from=>$from,
            until=>$until
        );

        search($list);
}

sub search {
    my $list = $_[0];
while ( my $record = $list->next ) { 
    my $datestamp = $record->header->datestamp;
    print "[ time stamp: ",$datestamp," ]","\n";
    my $metadata = $record->metadata;
    print "Title: ",$metadata->title,"\n";
    [...]}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Changed answer due to feedback*

Try `chomp`ing your input. It may confuse the module you are passing the values to. E.g. change

```
    my $from = <STDIN>;
```

to

```
    chomp(my $from = <STDIN>);
```

Comment: Oh sorry, the global variable was something I wanted to delete it came from another try ... but I made the globals local now (see edited code above) and it still does not work.

Comment: Then you can try the advice I gave 2 hours ago and chomp your STDIN input. Maybe that will help.

Comment: I'll change my answer.